# Python script not working using -> driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path, options=chrome_options)

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, google-forms

i'm trying to create a script that tries every possiblity in a google form but i'm noobie so i ask my dear friend GPT and there is what i got

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Charger le formulaire Google

driver.get('https://https://docs.google.com/forms/URL')

# Attendre un court instant pour que la page se charge complètement

time.sleep(2)

# Réponses possibles pour chaque question

question1_responses = ['reponse1', 'reponse2']
```

And a lot more but this first part isn't working, it could be a stupid mistake from me because it's my first time using python. So the error is :

```
script.py", line 15, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path, options=chrome_options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'
```

I downloaded ChromeDriver 94.0.4606.41 from https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

and put the chromedriver.exe in the same directory as the script, and i added it in the path of environment variable

I already tried to  install or update Selenium :

```
pip install selenium
pip install --upgrade selenium
```

At the beginning the script was like that (but idk what it really changes)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from itertools import product
import time

# Chemin vers le fichier exécutable du navigateur Chrome
chrome_driver_path = '/chemin/vers/chromedriver'

# Options du navigateur Chrome
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')  # Exécution en arrière-plan sans ouvrir de fenêtre de navigateur

# Initialisation du navigateur Chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path, options=chrome_options)

# Charger le formulaire Google
driver.get('https://docs.google.com/forms/your-form-url')

# Attendre un court instant pour que la page se charge complètement
time.sleep(2)

# Réponses possibles pour chaque question
```

Comment: The `executable_path` argument has been removed in the current version of Selenium. Get rid of it.

Comment: Ok, thx i'm not using it anymore i'm using the first version on the post, but it doesn't resolve the error 

Comment: Please post the full error message including the traceback. What you posted earlier is incomplete.